# How to set condition of a NaN value to show/hide a view using ngIf | angular 6

Tags: angular, if-statement, angular-ng-if

I want to hide a label when the value is `NAN` using `*ngIf*` but it's not working.

[image]

The marked label is the default value of a variable, once the input is filled the value will be a number
I want to show the label only when the value is not `NAN`

**What tried**

```
     // undefined
    <mat-hint *ngIf="this.cost_liter !== 'undefined'" >cost/liter: {{this.cost_liter}}</mat-hint>
   // 'undefined'
    <mat-hint *ngIf="this.cost_liter !== 'undefined'" >cost/liter: {{this.cost_liter}}</mat-hint>
    //!=
    <mat-hint *ngIf="this.cost_liter != undefined" >cost/liter: {{this.cost_liter}}</mat-hint>
    //!== NAN
    <mat-hint *ngIf="this.cost_liter !== NAN" >cost/liter: {{this.cost_liter}}</mat-hint>
     //!= NAN
  <mat-hint *ngIf="this.cost_liter != NAN" >cost/liter: {{this.cost_liter}}</mat-hint>
     //!== null
   <mat-hint *ngIf="this.cost_liter !== null" >cost/liter: {{this.cost_liter}}</mat-hint>
    // != null
   <mat-hint *ngIf="this.cost_liter != null" >cost/liter: {{this.cost_liter}}</mat-hint>
```

i am sure that **ngIf** is working, since i set a condition if the value greater than 0. and it works, but still not my need

```
    // > 0
   <mat-hint *ngIf="this.cost_liter != null" >cost/liter: {{this.cost_liter}}</mat-hint>
```

Comment: It's a funny little quirk of JavaScript that `NaN != NaN`, so your comparison there will always return true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use JavaScript method `isNAN(this.cost_liter)` to check or you can use `Number.isNaN()`.

Use `if (Number.isNaN(this.cost_liter))`

Both methods return true or false, and returns false if the value is null.

This is how you do:

```
<mat-hint *ngIf="!Number.isNaN(this.cost_liter)" >cost/liter: {{this.cost_liter}}</mat-hint>
```

Or you can define a method in the component and call each time you need it.

```
isNumber(value) {
  return Number.isNaN(value);
}
```

And use in the template:

```
<mat-hint *ngIf="!isNumber(this.cost_liter)" >cost/liter: {{this.cost_liter}}</mat-hint>
```

Answer (score 6):

Since the method isNan is not know in you template , you can declare it in the component :

```
isNaN: Function = Number.isNaN;
```

then in your template call it like this :

```
<mat-hint *ngIf="!isNAN(this.cost_liter)" >cost/liter: {{this.cost_liter}}</mat-hint>
```

Regards,

Comment: please can you specify where to add the `isNaN` function in the ts component ? i tried to add it in the class declaration, but not working, and in the `ngOnInit()` but still not working, Regards

Comment: you should add it as an attribute of your component :
export class yourComponent {
isNaN: Function = Number.isNaN;
constructor(){}
}

Comment: this is exactly what i tried but i am getting this error `FuelContainerComponent.html:28 ERROR TypeError: _co.isNAN is not a function`

Comment: can you show how did you use it in the html template ? ( as you can see the error is in your html )

Comment: ts: `isNaN: Function = Number.isNaN;
  constructor(private fuelContServ: FuelContainerService,private modalService: NgbModal,public snackBar: MatSnackBar) {}`

html:`<input matInput formControlName="totalPrice" placeholder="Total Price" type="number" [(ngModel)]="this.totalPrice" name="nameInput" (ngModelChange)="this.cost_liter=this.totalPrice/this.totalLiters">
              <mat-hint *ngIf="!isNAN(this.cost_liter)" >cost/liter: {{this.cost_liter}}</mat-hint>`

Comment: what is the type of the attribute cost_liter ?

Comment: it is declared `cost_liter=0;`